# How to change border color to background color if background is gradient?

Tags: html, css

I would like to change bottom border of my active menu item to website background color so it looks like an open tab but my background is gradient so it has different color in different parts of the website. How do i do that. I can't change it to none because i have another border that goes under the entire menu that i need to cover.
Here is the link to my website
http://woodworkingoc.com.hostasp.info/

Comment: If the bottom border will always appear in the same place relative to the background color on all browsers, then just identify the color at that particular point. There are color picker utilities you can use to sample it out of the browser if that's what you're having trouble doing.

Comment: Not that I endorse this method; you should probably just use an image; but what you can do is print screen your web page, paste it in an image editor, zoom into where the line will be and use the eye dropper tool to determine the hex color of the gradient BG which is directly next to your border line. Use that color...

Comment: @kinakuta depending on user's screen size it will probably differ slightly but if there are no other methods I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I examined your `.CSS` file.

For `nav > ul li.current` you have `background` property with prefixes for FF, IE and Chrome. But something wrong with this property, so Chrome and FF hide this property in web inspector and not apply it to element. If write property correctly, gradient is applied to `li` element and overlayed bottom border of `<div id="layout-navigation" class="group">`.

Use gradient generator (like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create correct gradient rules. For example:

```
nav > ul li.current {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #B9BDBF), color-stop(100%, #5C5E5F)) fixed;
}
```

Comment: I tried colorzilla and their autogenerated gradient are messed up. They sometimes come out as a bunch of stripes or if the page is half screen then the gradient looks like two gradients copied each on half the page. I am reallly happy with the ones I have. They are very subtle but I like them.